# Cycles Baking to .EXR - Workflow questions!

Tags: cycles-render-engine, baking

I baked lightmaps for several objects for my archviz Scene into .exr and now i want to tonemap the maps and save them as 16bit-.png for final use in my shaders.

The tonemapping with Reinhard in the Compositor gives me a good result, Problem is that if I run the Operator with the same Settings, the resulting maps do not look coherent (difference in brightness/contrast).

I think this is to be expected, because every object captures different luminance values and there is no reference to the value range of the whole Scene. I definetly would like to generate maps with value range from 0-1 as 16bit-.pngs (to avoid banding), because we will afterwards render texture-overlay and reflections on top in Cycles and if I take underlying .exrs I think I will need more samples for final Rendering to clean up noise. (render time is critical, 5min Animation / 360°- pano-movie / 8K).

Thank you all in advance for every idea or answer regarding this Topic!